# Run a scala project using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: scala, jupyter

I have a project, it uses Scala programming language. I have some experiments in it. I want to open and run my project using `Jupyter notebook` , so that I can easily distribute it to my peers.
please help on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not understand why you need a Scala Project in `Jupyter notebook` in stead of building in `sbt` or `Maven` . If you are thinking about scripting in Scala than you can try out `Ammonite` which gives you easy importing and almost Python like ability for scripting. I think there is an extension called 
`Jupyter Scala` which gives you Scala support , but I have not used it yet.

Comment: See I have a project which contains different examples and after running an example we get visualization and graph. So will it be possible to create a notebook for it. Also please guide me on how to add my project packages and libraries.

Comment: Just try out Ammonite as a scala scripting platform. It's more or less like Ipython and read it's documentation for easy importing packages . I think there must be some builtin library in scala for visualization.

Comment: Does ammonite notebook works same as jupyter notebook and is easily shareable to peers.

Comment: Ammonite is just for easily installing packages without building anything. You can take it as a Scripting platform and you can share the Scala scripts. For  jupyter notebook like capabilities look into Jupyter Scala.